# How to get CSS to link to HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to coding, but have the basics down for the most part. I recently downloaded Atom and created very simple HTML and CSS files. I used the standard link method (as shown in the code), but cannot seem to get my css to link. My only install thus far has been webBoxio/atom-html-preview.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
 <body>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mine.css">
         <h1>test</h1>
         <p>test</p>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1, p {
    font-family: Sans-Serif ;
}
```

Comment: Is your HTML page in the same directory as your mine.css file? If so, then your link is correct. If not, then you'll have to code that path relative to wherever mine.css is located. Not sure what this has to do with atom.

Comment: is your HTML file and CSS file in the same folder, or are they each in their own separate files?

Comment: I believe so.. they're in the same folder if that's the same thing.

Comment: Your link method is far away from standard. `<link` element must be in `<head>` block, not in `<body>`.

Comment: Yes. Your link element should be in the head section of your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others said in the comments, the `<link>` tag should go between `<head>` and `</head>` tags. 
So the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mine.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>test</h1>
     <p>test</p>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

However, your code worked for me on Firefox.

Also, I suggest you this website if you wanna learn html (if you haven't found it yet): http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is both files need to be in the same directory. Had the same problem and couldn't figure it out until I changed that. Both HTML and .CSS need to be in the same folder, not in the same folder within the other. Hope this helps other peeps in the future.